# SQL Server: Find out default value of a column with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, default

How can I find out the default value of a column in a table using a SQL query?

By using this stored procedure:

```
sp_columns @tablename
```

I get some information on the columns of a particular table but the default value of the columns is missing, How can I get it?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can find the stored definition with the below (remember to adjust the column and table name to find to be ones relevant to your environment!)

```
SELECT object_definition(default_object_id) AS definition
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  name      ='colname'
AND    object_id = object_id('dbo.tablename')
```

Comment: This returns nothing for me on sql server 2008... and I know for a fact that my schema / table / field names are correct, and that there is indeed a default.

Comment: @Amalgovinus it definitely works. Are you running it in the right database context? Does the account you are running the query under have sufficient permissions to see the definition?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have permissions. In other circumstances Mssql is "nice" enough to tell you you can't access things like sysobjects, etc., but in this case it just pretends as if there's nothing to show if you're not using a database on which you have permission. I had to set a default database for this to work at all. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362434/how-can-i-change-my-default-database-in-sql-server-without-using-ms-sql-server-m

Comment: If a varchar's default is '', then it returns NULL for definition.

Answer (score 32):

I use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table like this:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName 
  AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 18):

Use:

```
   SELECT so.name AS table_name, 
          sc.name AS column_name, 
          sm.text AS default_value
     FROM sys.sysobjects so
     JOIN sys.syscolumns sc ON sc.id = so.id
LEFT JOIN sys.syscomments sm ON sm.id = sc.cdefault
    WHERE so.xtype = 'U' 
      AND so.name = @yourtable
 ORDER BY so.[name], sc.colid
```