# Creating SQL Server database without the /MSSQLSERVER in the connection string?

Tags: sql-server

I found this pretty weird thing when I first installed SQL Server 2008, for some reason there are two things that I want to get rid of and I can't:

1. If my computer name is, say, ABC, then I always have to connect to ABC/MSSQLSERVER for the server name when I log in from the SQL Server client, instead of using just using ABC, may I know how I can do that?
2. How can I default the DB so that if I have multiple DB on the server (System DB + my real DB), I can always default to use my real DB without saying "Use MyRealDB" every time?

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Anyi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) When installing, you picked [a named instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531.aspx).

2) In user admin, you can [specify the default database per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362434/how-can-i-change-my-default-database-in-sql-server-without-using-ms-sql-server-ma).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So do I have to uninstall and reinstall for fix the first issue or I can simply convert the named instance to default instance somehow? And where I can choose to install named instance? I am using MS-SQL Server 2008 in Windows Server 2008 R2. Thanks!

Comment: I did a quick search to confirm what I thought, but the only way to change it is to reinstall.

Comment: Oh, well, I guess then I am out of luck then, OK, I'll try to reinstall tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. What's happened here is that your SQL Server is installed as a *named instance*. To remedy this, you'll have to remove and reinstall SQL Server.