# How do you get Management Studio to actually use the default database/catalog for a user's login?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This is relatively similar to questions such as these:

[How can I change my default database in SQL Server without using MS SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362434/how-can-i-change-my-default-database-in-sql-server-without-using-ms-sql-server-m)

https://superuser.com/questions/364825/sql-server-management-studio-ignores-default-db

That being said, Management Studio is ignoring all the suggestions.  I'm logging in as sa, and I can see that the default catalog for sa is being changed successfully, but Management Studio ignores these changes in the dropdown:

[image]

Even if I change it to `specific_database_name`, and even if I can look at the sa login Properties menu and see that it's set to `specific_database_name`, Management Studio will always default that combo box to `master`.

I've tried:

1. `Exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='sa', @defdb='specific_database_name'`
2. `ALTER LOGIN  sa
   WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = specific_database_name`
3. Going into the Properties menu for login sa in Management Studio and setting it in the dropdown box there.

The OP in the second question eventually fell back to using a batch file to log in as a different user, but I'd personally just rather keep having `master` show up.  Also he did mention being able to set this on the connection properties themselves, but it's greyed out on my system, and I seem to remember being able to set this for an individual user a long time ago on another machine.

How can this be set?  Note that this is not using a Windows login, but a SQL Server one instead.  Thanks.

Comment: If it's a windows login, then it's probably inheriting it from the group. Besides, it's working as expected for me, and always did.

Comment: It works fine for me.  How exactly are you creating the database window?  Give us explicit steps so the we can reproduce this.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I open Management Studio, and I enter sa's password in the credentials pop-up.  Everything else is pre-populated.  Then I just click Connect, then New Query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why these methods are not working. Just to be sure I just did the following (on SQL Server 2012 enterprise)

```
1) Created Login test and assigned x1 as default database
2) Added login test to database x1 (and made test a member of datareaders)
3) Reopened SSMS - Logged in as Test
4) Opened query window - was placed in x1.
```

You really want to make users default to a database that is not a system database - otherwise they will attempt to create objects in Master which is something you really want to avoid.