# Set a default database for a specific SSMS project, NOT for a user/login?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using Solutions and Projects in SQL Server Management Studio to organize my scripts and files. I want to set a default database for a project so that when I start a new script file it will start with that database selected, instead of "master" which is the SQL login's default. I do not want to change the default database for the login, only the project.

Can this be done? I have searched online and cannot find it. I keep getting results for changing the default database for a login which I do not want.

I checked the Project properties but there is no setting for this. I also checked the project's connection properties, but there appears to be nothing in there.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible direction:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362434/how-to-change-default-database-in-sql-server-without-using-ms-sql-server-managem   Be sure to read the comments

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, that won't work because that question is for changing the default database for the SQL login. I need to change it for the SSMS Project specifically, not the login. If it is even possible. I am thinking probably not since I cannot find anything on it while searching online nor can I find the setting in the Project properties.

Comment: So create a Service Account per project.

Comment: This would be purely a SSMS thing but I don't think it is possible.